# How to resize a long table attribute for a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resize, ruby-on-rails-3.2, html-table

I have a long column attribute in my table, it is a token, and I want it to be displayed in two rows instead of one since the token is taking a lot of table space.

For example: "`44b4bf4c01261542c9e34701fe435e55`"

Code snippet:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="admin_data_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>request</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
    <tr>
    <td><%= @request.token %></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

---

How can I make this long value `44b4bf4c01261542c9e34701fe435e55` shorter for example to be like:

```
44b4bf4c012615
42c9e34701fe
435e55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use String's scan method to break it up into bits and then join it back together.  Here's an example breaking it up into a maximum of 15 characters per line.

```
> str = "44b4bf4c01261542c9e34701fe435e55"
 => "44b4bf4c01261542c9e34701fe435e55"
> puts str.scan(/.{0,15}/).join("\n")
44b4bf4c0126154
2c9e34701fe435e
55
```

Comment: String#scan works by matching on the supplied regex and passing the result to a block (or in this case an array).  That regex matches 0-15  characters.  That results in a 3 element array which we then join back together.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frontend view concern. You should use HTML or CSS to deal with the width of the column instead of transforming the data itself.

You can do so by setting the HTML width, for example:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="admin_data_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th width='10%'>request</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
    <tr>
    <td width='10%'><%= @request.token %></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

You could use css by:

```
admin_data_table .token-column { width: 10% }
```

Or if you still feel like transforming the data generated in the backend, you can split the token string with ruby like this:

```
<%= @token.each_slice(10) # will produce an array of chunks of 10 characters %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is a front-end concern. You could try this in your css

```
table td 
{
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:20%; 
  overflow:hidden;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Hope that helps